# Make bash automatically present successive interactive commands, but keep the interaction manual

Tags: bash, shell, sh, interactive-shell

I need to run the `$ aspell -c file.txt` command on about 300 files. I want bash to run the `aspell -c <FILENAME>` for me for each file in the list, but allow me to do the interaction. So, for example:

1. Bash presents `$aspell -c file1.txt`
2. I interact with the spellchecker, and fix all spelling errors in file1.txt
3. Bash presents `$aspell -c file2.txt`
4. I interact with the spellchecker, and fix all spelling errors in file2.txt
5. Bash presents `$aspell -c file3.txt`
   ...

So on.

Is there a way to ask bash to run an interactive command, wait until the interaction is complete, and then run the next interactive command?

Thanks!

Comment: If the files are in the same directory, otherwise replace * with your file list: for f in *; do aspell -c $f; done

Comment: Yeah, I realized that I could just loop through the files in some way after posting this. :) Can you present it as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks!

Comment: nevermind :) happy coding!